# two screen widths: 375px and 1024px

Tags: css, css-selectors, media-queries

How do I build a website at two screen widths: 375px and 1024px? the website need not respond to widths between the two.

@media only screen and (min-width : 375px) and (max-width : 1024px)
As far as I know this tag media work between 375 and 1024. Perhaps using breakpoint is the right approach. Any suggestion?

Comment: you want to `max-width: 375px` and build for anything below, that would be your `screen1` and then `min-width: 1024` that woudl be `screen2`

Comment: Yes, you can use media query for particular devices. For specific screen you can add break point like 362px to 456px and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving **media queries for all devices with portrait mode also** . I am given the media query CSS using breakpoint also. Use this media query for the better use and also the portrait devices include in this answer:

```
/* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

  //CSS

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always best to design your CSS `mobile-first`, which means that your CSS file looks a little like this:

```
CSS:
// Basic CSS
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 375px) {
  div {
    height: 150px;
  } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

This way you have a div that renders in three different ways on your breakpoints

1. 0 - 374px it's a square of 200x200 pixels with a yellow background
2. 375px - 1023px it's a rectangle of 150x200 pixels with a yellow background
3. 1024px and up it's a rectangle of 100x200 pixels with a red background

This way you don't repeat yourself too much, your code stays clean and you only override what is necessary.